# IEnumerable evaluation

Tags: c#

In this implementation does hand will be evaluated each time and return another list ?

```
foreach (Card card in hand.Cards)
{ 

}
```

Should we replace the above implementation with  the following?

```
var cards = hand.Cards;
foreach (Card card in cards)
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Actually the two snippets result in the same code. 
In the snippet below:

```
foreach (Card card in hand.Cards)
{ 

}
```

`hand.Cards` is going to be called only once.

Edit:

I've created a small snippet, that I hope will show that there is no difference at all:

```
void Main()
{
    Hand hand = new Hand();
    foreach( var card in hand.Cards() )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", card);
    }

    var allCards = hand.Cards();
    foreach( var anotherCard in allCards )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", anotherCard);
    }
}

public class Card
{
private string _cardName;
public Card( string cardName )
    {
        this._cardName = cardName;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this._cardName;
    }
}

public class Hand
{
    public IEnumerable<Card> Cards()
    {
        yield return new Card("Ace");
        yield return new Card("King");
    }
}
```

The otuput (for both methods) is as follows:

```
Ace
King
Ace
King
```

Comment: thank you for u detailed answer can you explain yield functionality please?

Comment: in this example - instead of returning a list of objects (Cards) and building them (which may take time) yield is used. yield returns one object at a time - it is quite convenient as very often objects are processed one by one. It may happen that the list of object could grow very big in this situation it could take significant amount of time to start processing the very first object. You will find even more detailed explanation of yield on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: forgot to add: I the sample above I just wanted to show you, that it doesn't matter which method you choose - you always get two cards: Ace and King.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no difference between this two. Also if they are for EF, they are same query. also in the syntax below:

```
foreach (Card card in hand.Cards.AsEnumerable())
{ 

}
```

the `hand.Cards.AsEnumerable()` will be evaluated at first and will be saved in temporary variable, actually this wont happen in each iteration.

P.S: in general there is no need to call AsEnumerable in foreach loop, I just mentioned this to elaborate foreach evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference.

But if you use `hand.Cards` in other code, yes the second should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The two code snippets you posted above are identical.  When you enumerate through a collection   that implement the IEnumerable interface, it uses the `GetEnumerator` method to loop through the items, and it does not create a duplicate copy of the object.

The only difference above is that you're creating a second variable that holds the same reference to the original collection, which doesn't do you any good in this case.